# mysql let two rows subtraction

Tags: mysql

Original table：

```
+----+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
| id | playnum_sum | real_playnum_sum | create_time         |
+----+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    100|                300| 2015-05-05 19:54:01 | 
|  2 |    200|                400| 2015-05-06 19:54:01 | 
|  3 |    300|                500| 2015-05-07 16:09:04 | 
+----+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to let every two lines subtraction,this is the result:

caculated table：

```
+----+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
| id | playnum_sum | real_playnum_sum | create_time         |
+----+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    100|100| 2015-05-06 19:54:01     (this is the second time in Origin table) | 
|  2 |    100|100| 2015-05-07 16:09:04    (this is the third time in Origin table) | 
+----+-------------+------------------+---------------------+
```

and please mind the create time.how to write the sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ids have no gaps you can do this with a self-join:

```
select oprev.id, o.playnum_sum - oprev.playnum_sum,
       o.real_playnum_sum - oprev.real_playnum_sum,
       o.create_time
from original o join
     original oprev
     on o.id = oprev.id + 1;
```